# style taskboard cards using their parent properties

Tags: azure-devops, taskmanager, product-management

in my sprint taskboard i want to style my tasks based on their parent PBI/bug priority and not having to set a priority for each task. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

As of this time, however, there isn't a built-in feature to set fields or styles of work items based on their parent fields or styles. Here is a [feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/copying-field-values-from-parent-work-item-by-crea/385158).

If you don't mind extra work, you can get and update fields of the work items through Rest API, and use automation tools such as Power Automate to let the script to run automatically when the a work item is created.